# How do I remove the bottom bullet from django table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I generate the following table using django_table2

```
Semester    Actual  Prediction
Spring 2014     209     199

    *1 coe
```

The semester, actual, and prediction are column names. My table is exactly how i need it. However, at the bottom of each table I always have the number of items in my model. I do not want that bullet. I know its default in django_table2. Is there a way to remove this? Below is another example:

```
Department  Semester        Actual  Prediction
MIE         2014 Spring     202     210
MIE         2015 Fall       213     200
MIE         2015 Spring     11      12

*3 departments
```

Comment: can you not just hide that via css ?

Comment: I think i can. but is that a heading?

Comment: I have no clue. You would have to inspect the element

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it (for me) is by creating this path (**your_templates_dir**/django_tables2/tables.html) on your templates directory with the following content:

```
{% spaceless %}
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% load i18n %}
{% if table.page %}
<div class="table-container">
{% endif %}
{% block table %}
<table{% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
    {% nospaceless %}
    {% block table.thead %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for column in table.columns %}
            {% if column.orderable %}
            <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}">{{ column.header }}</a></th>
            {% else %}
            <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>{{ column.header }}</th>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% endblock table.thead %}
    {% block table.tbody %}
    <tbody>
        {% for row in table.page.object_list|default:table.rows %} {# support pagination #}
        {% block table.tbody.row %}
        <tr class="{{ forloop.counter|divisibleby:2|yesno:"even,odd" }}"> {# avoid cycle for Django 1.2-1.6 compatibility #}
            {% for column, cell in row.items %}
                <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{% if column.localize == None %}{{ cell }}{% else %}{% if column.localize %}{{ cell|localize }}{% else %}{{ cell|unlocalize }}{% endif %}{% endif %}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endblock table.tbody.row %}
        {% empty %}
        {% if table.empty_text %}
        {% block table.tbody.empty_text %}
        <tr><td colspan="{{ table.columns|length }}">{{ table.empty_text }}</td></tr>
        {% endblock table.tbody.empty_text %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    {% endblock table.tbody %}
    {% block table.tfoot %}
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    {% endblock table.tfoot %}
    {% endnospaceless %}
</table>
{% endblock table %}

{% if table.page %}
{% with table.page.paginator.count as total %}
{% with table.page.object_list|length as count %}
{% block pagination %}
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if table.page.has_previous %}
    {% nospaceless %}{% block pagination.previous %}<li class="previous"><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=table.page.previous_page_number %}">{% trans "Previous" %}</a></li>{% endblock pagination.previous %}{% endnospaceless %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if table.page.has_previous or table.page.has_next %}
    {% nospaceless %}{% block pagination.current %}<li class="current">{% blocktrans with table.page.number as current and table.paginator.num_pages as total %}Page {{ current }} of {{ total }}{% endblocktrans %}</li>{% endblock pagination.current %}{% endnospaceless %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if table.page.has_next %}
    {% nospaceless %}{% block pagination.next %}<li class="next"><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=table.page.next_page_number %}">{% trans "Next" %}</a></li>{% endblock pagination.next %}{% endnospaceless %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock pagination %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

This approach will override all of the tables you create via django_table2 template tag and won't necessary work with upcoming versions of django_table2, but I'll be OK if you want to keep an specific version (in my case 0.15.0).

Another approach, which is more scalable, should work with future versions (and I recommend) is by subclassing Table, like described on the [django-tables2 documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-template).